# C++ - How to remember if a file has already been moved?

Tags: c++, file

Right now I have a program that moves files automatically from one folder to another only once.
So if that file gets into that folder again, it shouldn't be moved.The application is being executed every 30 minutes.

So right now what I have is if LastWriteTime is older than 30 minutes, don't move it. It works, but using time to evaluate this isn't good practice, and we already had several bugs that came along with it.

To elaborate further, we have a seperate 3rd party application that checks coming files in, say, `C:\main\`

It moves files to `C:\main\failed` if it detects problems with that file. Now what my script does is it moves them to `C:\main\` one more time(to check for file problems again) and if it comes back to `C:\main\failed`, then keep it there.

I'm also aware of tracking these informations into a seperat file, but it could have problems blowing up memory wise once a bug occurs. Are there alternative, better ways to do it?

Comment: Keep a `._move_history.txt` file in your system's equivalent of `/tmp`?

Comment: Do these files have any sort of regular naming scheme?  Can you check the location you are moving files to, and see if it already exists there?

Comment: @scohe001 What's tmp's 'schedule' to clear up files? From what I've read, it only clears tmp when booted, which isn't optimal since the Windows server runs 24/7

Comment: @Spottel why is that not optimal? Are you doing so many moves that a text file could grow large enough to cause problems? If so, you can write some code to cleanup the file (remove any entries older than eg. 24hrs) whenever you load it.

Comment: The naming scheme varies, there's no single pattern unfortunately (we also have different customers...)
To elaborate further, we have a seperate 3rd party application that checks files in, say, C:\main\.   It moves files to C:\main\failed if it detects problems with that file. Now what my script does is it moves them to C:\main\ one more time(to check for file problems again) and if it comes back to C:\main\failed, then keep it there.

Comment: @scohe001 That could work but I need to check the time of these entries specifically. A possibility would be to add date and time to each of those entries and compare them with the current time. That's still sort of time based, but that's definetly a better solution that what I have currently.

Comment: @Spottel from what you've said, time shouldn't play a part in whether you move a file or not, no? Your only criteria is whether the file was in this directory before. So wouldn't it just be a lookup in your history file for whether the file was moved to this directory before? Can you [edit] your question to give an example (File `A.txt` is at `/First/Path/A.txt`. Then, it gets moved to...)? I think I may not be completely understanding what you want.

Comment: @scohe001 I apologize, I was refering to your comment as to removing entries that are older than X hours. That could work, I would have to remove them depending on whether they're older than x hours to prevent these files from blowing up as you said. Post is edited.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If there are only two locations like you mention in your example (ie: a `/main/` and a `/main/failed/`), then you really only need to know the file name, and how many times before you've moved it. So you could store a file in `/tmp/` like:

```
file_1.txt 1
file_7.txt 2
another_file.txt 1
...
```

Then in pseudo code, your program could look like:

```
unordered_map<string, unsigned int> file_count;
ifstream file_handle("/tmp/._move_history.txt");

// Load up the contents of the file into memory
string file_name;
unsigned int count;
while(file_handle >> file_name >> count) { file_count[file_name] = count; }

vector<string> files_to_move = get_files_in_fail_dir();

// Loop through the files and move them if applicable
for(auto file_to_move : files_to_move) {
    if(file_count[file_to_move] > 1) { continue; } // moved twice, don't touch
    move_file(file_to_move);
    file_count[file_to_move]++; // Increment how many times we've moved it
}

file_handle.close();
ofstream out("/tmp/._move_history.txt");

// Write back to the history file
for(auto [file_name, count_moved] : file_count) {
    // TODO: if you're worried about big files, filter what you write here
    ofstream << file_name << ' ' << count_moved << '\n';
}
```

This'll write a single line in the history file for each file you've ever moved. I would only really worry about the size of that file if you're moving 10's of thousands of unique files. If that's the case, you could continue incrementing the int you're storing in the file each time you see a file (even if you're skipping it because you've already seen it twice). So the move loop could look like:

```
for(auto file_to_move : files_to_move) {
    // moved twice, don't touch. But increment anyways
    if(file_count[file_to_move]++ > 1) { continue; } 
    move_file(file_to_move);
    // file_count[file_to_move]++; // Already incremented in the if, don't do it again here
}
```

Then when you're writing back to the file, you can say if you've seen a file, say, 100 times (100 * 30 min = 50hrs =~ 2days), then don't write it back:

```
for(auto [file_name, count_moved] : file_count) {
    if (count_moved > 100) { continue; } // We've seen it 100 times, forget about it
    ofstream << file_name << ' ' << count_moved << '\n';
}
```

That 100 is something you'll need to decide based on your business rules here. How long do you need to remember a file? How many files are you dealing with in total, so how big will the history file grow? This is something you'll need to test with and tweak to your liking.